# Does Bell's theorem have anything to say about the locality or realism of Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, probability, locality

In the original paper written by Bell, it's clear to me that what he's really trying to answer is what class of Classical Theories (that obey the laws of classical probability theory) can replicate the observations of Quantum Mechanics? And in considering this he rules out the possibility of such classical theories being both local and counter-factual definite.

What's not at all clear to me is how people take this to imply that Quantum Mechanics cannot be both local and counter-factual definite. But Quantum Mechanics is Quantum Mechanics, it's a framework for calculating probabilities and it's proven to be amazingly accurate and Bell's theorem doesn't touch this. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Your class of classical theories, defined by obeying standard probability, is simply the in fact the counter factual things (which do not happen) being definite, and one gets normal probability theory that says that those are the elements of physical reality. Physical reality means things happen or are there or not, and it's just counting, and thus standard probability. There is plenty better explanations on journals and online thatn anything anybody can state here.